# g++ in python - macro containing various characters can not be passed

Tags: python, c++, macros, g++

In my `django` python project I used to invoke my `C++` script via `g++`:

```
os.system('g++ -std=c++0x mutualcepepe.cpp -D "threshold = ' + str(thresh) + '" -o mutualout')
```

"thresh" was a simple float variable. It worked but the idea of whole project changed a bit and now I want to pass a string containing different let's say "type" of characters.
I will show my problem on the example and in this case my macro "djangoname" (not a "threshold" anymore) is  ">gi|111>gi|222>gi|333>gi|444". 
Invocation:

```
os.system('g++ -std=c++0x mutualcepepe.cpp -D "djangoname = ' + str(filename2only) + '" -o mutualout')
```

Errors I get in the terminal:

```
mutualcepepe.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
<command-line>: 0:14: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
mutualcepepe.cpp: 
99:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘djangoname’ string filename
to_string(djangoname);
                          ^

<command-line>:0:15: error: ‘gi’ was not declared in this scope
mutualcepepe.cpp:99:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘djangoname’
string filename = to_string(djangoname);
```

I think the point is, that when g++ compilator "read" what the macro contains, it some kinda divides it, when it gets special character, or when after number it reads letter, because after that it treat it as a integer not a string data. So my question is, is it possible to pass in g++ the macro (or anyhow "string variable") containing "different type" of characters, in the way which g++ compiler will run without the problem?

I wondered about translation some "unconvinient" characters for other ones, and turned them back in c++ script, but I can't be sure what my macro will contain, that depend on users who will use my net app.

To be honest I have an idea to avoid it, but it is totally silly and connected with senseless opening new files and reading from them what take time.

Mabye I'm wrong and the problem has different nature, I hope You will be able to help me or give helpful advise.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the macro explicitly a string, like e.g.

```
os.system('g++ ... -Ddjangoname="' + ... + '" ...')
```

Note the placement of the double-quotes.

Comment: Still get same errors, I changed it as You said, correct right?
                       os.system('g++ -std=c++0x mutualcepepe.cpp -Ddjangoname="' + str(filename2only) + '" -o mutualout')

Answer (score 0):

`os.system('g++ ...')` doesn't directly starts the g++ process. It actually starts whatever is configured as the default shell (e.g. /bin/sh) and the command line is then interpreted by the shell.

To avoid this unnecessary hoop and its complications, you can directly execute g++ with Python's subprocess.Popen and its communicate() method. This allows you to pass command line arguments as an array.

For example :

```
import sys, subprocess
filename2only = '">gi|111>gi|222>gi|333>gi|444"'
args = [
    'g++',
    '-std=c++0x', 'mutualcepepe.cpp',
    '-Ddjangoname=' + str(filename2only),
    '-omutualout'
]
p = subprocess.Popen(args=args, bufsize=-1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
sys.stdout.write(stdout)
sys.stderr.write(stderr)
if p.returncode != 0: sys.stderr.write('failed with exit code: ' + str(p.returncode))
```

This passes a `-Ddjangoname=">gi|111>gi|222>gi|333>gi|444"` option to the compiler, which is equivalent to `#define djangoname ">gi|111>gi|222>gi|333>gi|444"`.

Note that `str(filename2only)` isn't strictly necessary in this case, but it has the nice property of supporting any type of value (string, int or float).

You could, e.g. do :

`filename2only = 12.3` to pass `-Ddjangoname=12.3`, which is equivalent to `#define djangoname 12.3`

`filename2only = 'a b c'` to pass `-Ddjangoname=a b c`, which is equivalent to `#define djangoname a b c`

`filename2only = '"a b c"'` to pass `-Ddjangoname="a b c"`, which is equivalent to `#define djangoname "a b c"`

`filename2only = '"a \\"b\\" c"'` to pass `-Ddjangoname="a \"b\" c"`, which is equivalent to `#define djangoname "a \"b\" c"`, i.e. djangoname is then the string literal `a "b" c`, which contains double quotes!

Comment: The point is, that I use subprocess this way, only for "./mutualout", so:

        command = "./mutualout"
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    output = process.communicate()

If i invoke os.system(....) without double quotes i get same errors as posted, with double quotes I get:
"g++: error: =gi|111gi|222gi|333gi|444: No such file or directory"

Comment: If you insist on using `os.system`, then, don't put a space between `-Ddjangoname=` and `"gi|111gi|222gi|333gi|444"`, otherwise the shell splits the stanza as 2 arguments, and so the compiler thinks you're defining `djangoname` to nothing (there's nothing after the `=`' sign), and thinks you're feeding "gi|111gi|222gi|333gi|444" as a source file. The code i provided does what you want in a less error-prone, and portable way.

Comment: Note that `subprocess.Popen` with `shell=True` calls your command through the shell rather than directly starting the mutualout program. My point about `subprocess.Popen` (with `shell=False`, which is the default) is that it's actually easier to use than `os.system`, despite more lines of code to type, because it eliminates a layer of complexity (hence it's also a little faster).

Comment: I did, what You said:
    os.system('g++ -std=c++0x mutualcepepe.cpp -Ddjangoname="' + str(filename2only) + '" -o mutualout')
And it only got worse:
<command-line>:0:12: error: ‘gi’ was not declared in this scope
<command-line>:0:15: error: unable to find numeric literal operator ‘operator"" gi’
mutualcepepe.cpp:100:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘djangoname’
  string filename = djangoname;
                    ^
<command-line>:0:21: error: unable to find numeric literal operator ‘operator"" gi’

Comment: @theCember Assuming filename2only is a string that begins and ends with double quotes, what's happening here is the shell receives the command line `g++ -std=c++0x mutualcepepe.cpp -Ddjangoname=""gi|111gi|222gi|333gi|444"" -o mutualout`, note that you have these `""` doubled double-quotes, which the shell just eliminates!, so in the end the compiler is invoked with `-Ddjangoname=gi|111gi|222gi|333gi|444`, i.e. you lost all your double quotes. I might repeat myself, but the code i provided does work!

Answer (score 0):

This problem has nothing to do with the shell or the compiler invocation, although I honestly think you would be well advised to use a different way to invoke the compiler from python, such as the `[subprocess`][1](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html) module.

Somewhere in your C++ program you have:

```
string filename = to_string(djangoname);
```

You are using the `-D` option to effectively insert

```
#define djangoname >gi|111>gi|222>gi|333>gi|444
```

at the beginning of your program. That means that your declaration of filename will be:

```
string filename = to_string(>gi|111>gi|222>gi|333>gi|444);
```

which makes no sense at all, neither to C++ nor to me. Hence the error message, which is saying that you cannot start an expression with the `>` operator.

I don't think that is what you meant, but I have no idea what you really want to do.

Comment: Okay i will try to translate ">" characters to other ones, mabye it will help. 
My filename will contain headers of nucleotides seqences from .fasta format and they just starts with ">" character, in addition to this i need to make a checksum of them.

Comment: If what you want is to inject a string constant into your program, you should include the double quotes in the macro or use the preprocessor stringify operator to make a compile-time literal. `std:to_string` is not the answer.

Comment: I replaced unconvinient characters (but it wasnt really necessary) so string looks like "gi|111gi|222gi|333gi|444", when I invoke with double quotes I get 
"g++: error: =gi|111gi|222gi|333gi|444: No such file or directory"

Comment: `-Ddjangoname='"the|filename|as|a|string"'`. Then just assign: `string filename = djangoname;`

Comment: I capture the macro in c++ exacly as You wrote, and with exact invocation
os.system('g++ -std=c++0x mutualcepepe.cpp -D djangoname= "' + str(filename2only) + '" -o mutualout')
I get same error: ""g++: error: =gi|111gi|222gi|333gi|444: No such file or directory"

Really don't have any idea how to figure it out..

Comment: @cember if you use os.system, you neef to pass both the single and the double quotes to the shell. That's one of the reasons subprocess is better. And watch out for spaces.